# How to start receiver, getting "lateinit property notificationManager has not been initialized"

Tags: kotlin, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I am trying to make an alarm that sends notification when application is closed. I created an Alarm Manager in the MainActivity and created an inner class for the BroadcastReceiver as soon as the `onReceive()` is triggered, I need to send a notification. The alarm works but each time it tries to send the notification, I get an error of

> 2020-03-25 13:19:33.166 15045-15045/com.kotlin.ambulantlcs
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.kotlin.ambulantlcs, PID: 15045
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.kotlin.ambulantlcs.ui.MainActivity$Receiver:
> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property
> notificationManager has not been initialized
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3997)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:267)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1992)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7777)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
> Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property notificationManager has not been initialized
> at com.kotlin.ambulantlcs.ui.MainActivity$Receiver.onReceive(MainActivity.kt:100)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3988)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:267) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1992) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7777) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)

See my whole code below:

```
import android.app.*
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.RemoteViews
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.NavOptions
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI
import com.kotlin.ambulantlcs.R
import com.kotlin.ambulantlcs.storage.SharedDataManager
import com.kotlin.ambulantlcs.ui.fragments.LoginFragmentDirections
import java.util.*


open class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var context: Context
    lateinit var alarmManager: AlarmManager
    val obj: MainActivity = this

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration
            .Builder(R.id.homeFragment, R.id.loginFragment)
            .build()

        setAlarm()

        if(SharedDataManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn) {
            var navOptions = NavOptions.Builder()
                .setPopUpTo(R.id.action_login_Home, true)
                .build()

            val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment)
            NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)
            navController.navigate(
                LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginHome()
            )
        } else {
            val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment )
            NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration)

        }
    }


    override fun onBackPressed() {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Function is not allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment), null)
    }

    fun setAlarm() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Create: ${Date().toString()}")
        context = this
        alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val seconds = 10 * 1000
        val intent = Intent(context, Receiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        Log.d("MainActivity", "SECONDS: ${seconds.toLong()}")
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  seconds.toLong(), seconds.toLong(), pendingIntent)
    }

    class Receiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
        lateinit var notificationManager : NotificationManager
        lateinit var notificationChannel : NotificationChannel
        lateinit var builder : Notification.Builder
        private val channelId = "i.apps.notifications"
        private val description = "Test notification"

        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
           Log.d("MainActivity", " Receiver: ${Date().toString()}")
            val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)

            val pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            val contentView = RemoteViews("com.kotlin.ambulantlcs",
                R.layout.activity_main)

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                    channelId,description,NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
                notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.GREEN
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(false)
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)

                builder = Notification.Builder(context, channelId)
                    .setContent(contentView)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            }else{

                builder = Notification.Builder(context)
                    .setContent(contentView)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            }
            notificationManager.notify(1234,builder.build())
        }
    }
}
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Your notificationManger is null (you dont initialize him). Try this:

```
if (notificationManager == null) {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
```

Comment: sorry, my bad. 
if (notificationManager == null) {
        notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as 
 NotificationManager
    }

Comment: Actually, `notificationManager == null` always returns false in Kotlin. Please see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables

Answer (score 0):

The reason the app crashes is that you don't initialize `notificationManager`. Instead of declaring it as `lateinit var` you could just initialize it in your `Receiver` class:

```
val notificationManager : NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`lateinit` variables now has property of `isInitialized`, which checks whether the variable has been initialized or not.
You can use it like this:

```
if (!this::notificationManager.isInitialized) {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}else {
//THE NOTIFICATION MANAGER IS INITIALIZED
}
```